# не выводится id нажатого элемента

Tags: jquery, функции, click

Есть такой код:

```js
$('.block_ch').click(
  function() {
    var attribute = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(attribute);
  }
);
```

Но по нажатию тишина. Где может быть ошибка? Функция находится в `$(document).ready` вместе с остальными работающими функциями `.click`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В случае если элемент генерируется, а не сразу есть в html коде - нужно использовать `.on`

```
$(document).on('click', '.class', function () {

});
```

У вас это, соответственно:

```
$(document).on('click', '.block_ch', function () {
    var attribute = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(attribute);
  }
);
```

Comment: для клика всегда использую `.on('click');`, для имитации клика `.click();` :3